# Как правильно работать с connection pool?

Tags: java-ee, servlet

Настроил connection pool следующим образом:

Файл context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource 
    name="jdbc/Supermarkets" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="20" maxWait="10000"
    username="postgres"
    password="12345"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/Supermarkets"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
/>
```

Подключаю следующим образом (код конструктора который находится в классе работы с определенной сущностью):

```
    InitialContext initContext= new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds;
    ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/Supermarkets");
    db = ds.getConnection();
```

Далее в сервлете где нужна работа с этой сущностью создаю экземпляр данного класса и работаю через него с бд. После чего в конце сервлета закрываю соединения с базой данных с помощью метода closeConnection данного класса.

```
public void closeConnection() {
    try {
        db.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Но connection pool явно неработает так как создаются 50 и более конектов.

Как правильно работать, чтобы connection pool работал?

P.S. другие методы решения (ORM и т.п.) не советовать. Нужно просто быстро доделать учебный проект.

Comment: maxIdle указано 20. Проходит время, а свободные соединение не убираются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не стоит делать Connection переменной класса. Лучше сделайте таковым DataSource.
Попробуйте получать Connection для каждого запроса, и, по возможности, сразу его закрывать.

```
    private Connection getConnection() {
       return ds.getConnection();
    }

    private void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
       try {
          if (connection != null)
              connection.close();
       } catch (SQLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    // Бизнес метод
    public void doSmth(){
       Connection con = getConnection();
       try{
       ...
       }
       finally{
          closeConnection(con);
       }   
    }
```